# Bootstrap Tabs & Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an application where I am using Bootstrap nag-tabs for some content that is interrelated.  I am trying to make it so that when a hot reload comes along the last selected tab is re-selected.  I am also trying to make it so that the last selected tab is reselected when the user comes back to the page after navigating away.  Here is the template:

```
<template name='admin'>
    <ul id='adminTabs' class='nav nav-tabs'>
        {{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
        <li class='active'><a href='#districtstab' data-toggle='tab'>Districts</a></li>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-users'}}
        <li><a href='#usertab' data-toggle='tab'>Users</a></li>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-schools'}}
        <li><a href='#schoolstab' data-toggle='tab'>Schools</a></li>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-classes'}}
        <li><a href='#classestab' data-toggle='tab'>Classes</a></li>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-lessons'}}
        <li><a href='#lessonstab' data-toggle='tab'>Lessons</a></li>
        {{/if}}

        {{>onlineuserstab}}

    </ul>
    <div class='tab-content'>
        {{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
        {{#isolate}}
        <div class='tab-pane active' id='districtstab'>
        {{>districts}}
        </div>
        {{/isolate}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-users'}}
        {{#isolate}}
        <div class='tab-pane' id='usertab'>
        {{>users}}
        </div>
        {{/isolate}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-schools'}}
        {{#isolate}}    
        <div class='tab-pane' id='schoolstab'>
        {{>schools}}
        </div>
        {{/isolate}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-classes'}}
        {{#isolate}}
        <div class='tab-pane' id='classestab'>
        {{>classesTemplate}}
        </div>
        {{/isolate}}
        {{/if}}

        {{#if isInRole 'admin, manage-lessons'}}
        {{#isolate}}
        <div class='tab-pane' id='lessonstab'>
            {{>lessons}}
        </div>
        {{/isolate}}
        {{/if}}

        <div class='tab-pane' id='onlinetab'>
        {{#isolate}}
        {{>onlineusers}}
        {{/isolate}}
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

How can I accomplish what I am after easily?

Comment: If you need to preserve some values on hot push reloads, use Sessions. They are the values preserved by design.

Comment: Or better use Cookies if you want the value to persist when user get back: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the hashes are getting used, and you have an URL like `/#classestab`, you could just check for the hash in the URL on template render and select the relevant tab:

```
Template.admin.rendered = function() {
  if (window.location.hash)
    $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: When clicking on the tabs the hash is not added to the location.

Comment: Replace the default click handler with one that comments out the `.preventDefault()`? Like:
`$('#adminTabs a').click(function (e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})`